# Function signature for generic numbers

Tags: rust

I am trying to make a few generic functions that work on numbers, but I'm struggling with the function signatures.

Perhaps I am attacking the problem from the wrong angle, but here is where I got on my own so far. I am not hellbent on making this work this way; so if I am attacking the problem (of creating a small lib of generally useful math functions) from the wrong angle, then by all means educate me.

Let's say I want a function, `add` that adds up two numbers:

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn add(a: Add, b: Add) -> Add::Output {
    a + b
}
```

This won't compile. Here is a playground though: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4589325b5c8d1f1b19440424878caa98

I get essentially two errors. The first:

```
error[E0393]: the type parameter `RHS` must be explicitly specified
 --> src/main.rs:8:11
  |
8 | fn add(a: Add, b: Add) -> Add::Output {
  |           ^^^ missing reference to `RHS`
  |
  = note: because of the default `Self` reference, type parameters must be specified on object types
```

I have read [the chapter on advanced traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html) in the Rust book, so i "sort-of/kind-of" understand the `RHS` message, but they attack the problem of adding the `Add` trait to your particular data structure (a `Point` in the example); but never show a function signature of a function that takes anything that can be added up. So I am a little lost.

The second error:

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
 --> src/main.rs:8:27
  |
8 | fn add(a: Add, b: Add) -> Add::Output {
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type
  |
  = note: specify the type using the syntax `<Type as std::ops::Add>::Output`
```

This goes away if I write `<i32 as Add>::Output`, but that is not what I want. I specifically want the function to work on anything that can be added up (assuming both `a` and `b` to be the same type).

Comment: That's not how you write generic functions in Rust: please read again the [chapter about generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-00-generics.html). You must write: `fn add<T: Add>(a: T, b: T) -> T::Output `.

Comment: Oh wow. Rust is hard. I thought I know this. Thanks a lot. I know it's a different question (should have included it), but can I "cast" something to `T` inside the function then? Say I wanted to double it, so `(a + b) * 2` -- I need the `Mul` also, it quickly gets very complicated.

Comment: @GormCasper complicated maybe, [but not impossible](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=8e4f321f78a04776c0ecf9cddd26371c). The worst part is the return type :)

Comment: @GormCasper Yup, this will get complicated quickly.  I suggest you ask a separate question for the conversion.  Short answer, you will need some trait implementing the conversion, like `Into<T>`, or maybe `num::cast::FromPrimitive<T>`.

Comment: @kazemakase The problem with that approach is that there is basically only a single type that is `Mul<i32>`, which is `i32` itself.

Comment: So maybe I am attacking it from the wrong angle. Maybe it is better to just say "I expect you to give me `i32`, always." And just go with that

Comment: @GormCasper If this covers your use case, that's certainly the easier way.  Otherwise I suggest looking into the `num` crate and the traits defined there – they make it a lot easier to implement generic functions operating on nubmers.

Comment: @GormCasper that's the easy way :) have a look at the [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate for more powerful generic capabilities.

Comment: @SvenMarnach and @kazemakase thanks a lot. I think I'll go with basic `ints` and `floats` for now, and then it can later be converted once all this is easier for me (just reading the docs of the num crate is difficult for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are conflating *traits* and *types*.

`Add` is a *trait*.  A trait can be implemented for a type or a class of types, but it is not a type itself.

Function arguments need to be declared with a *type*, not a trait.  This is the main problem with your prototype – `Add` is not a type, so you can't use it as the type of a variable or a function argument.

Rust allows you to declare *generic types*, essentially type variables.  You can then place *trait bounds* on the generic types, which require that whatever type is substituted for the generic type must implement some trait. Your example using a generic type parameter `T` looks like this:

```
fn add<T: Add>(a: T, b: T) -> T::Output
```

This prototype requires that `a` and `b` both have the same type `T`, and that `T` implements the `Add` trait.